# ElastAlert - override run_every in config.yaml

Tags: yaml, elastalert

Is it possible to override the `run_every` attribute in the config.yaml?

Basically I have a `config.yaml` that has the following line:

```
run_every:
    seconds: 30
```

Now I have five rules that are using this `config.yaml`.  So all of them are running every 30 seconds.  On the fifth rule I want to run every 60 seconds however if I put the following line in my `fifth-rule.yaml`:

```
run_every:
    seconds: 60
```

It still runs every 30 seconds.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by creating different config.yaml for the rule that needs 60 seconds and feeding it via configuration option to elastalert.py.

By default elastalert.py uses config.yaml
This can be overriden with --config option as below:

```
python elastalert/elastalert.py --config configoverride.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

In each rule you can a shared settings file via the "import" command.
"If specified includes all the settings from this yaml file. This allows common config options to be shared. Note that imported files that aren’t complete rules should not have a .yml or .yaml suffix so that ElastAlert doesn’t treat them as rules."